# How to convert the value of JTextArea line count to Dimension height_JAVA

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, converters, formula

I am trying to set height in ScrollPane based on the returned value of getLineCount function in JTextArea.
When I set the value as height in Dimension of ScrollPane, it's really tiny. I've added *20 to get the result closest to what I am expecting.
However, with this trick, the higher number the getLineCount is, the less accurate it becomes which means that the height of JScrollPane becomes larger than what I am hoping for.

I need a formula to convert the metrics between them. However I don't know exactly what metric they are returning/using except they are int values.

If there is a built in library to convert these two, it might be useful as well.
There doesn't seem many online posts regarding this issue. Has anyone encountered this problem?

```
int height= textArea.getLineCount(); 
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1, height* 20));
```

Comment: What is the point of this? If you try to resize the scrollpane to be the size of the text area then there is no need for the scrollpane.

Comment: [`JTextArea#setRows`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setRows-int-)

Comment: @camickr I understand you raising the question. I know that generally it's pointless to set certain heights in scroll pane. However, I need to set certain heights at this stage to view the full text of JTextArea and in the future I will implement a function to reduce it to the certain height. Once it's reduced, I will use scrollbar in the scrollpane. To make the future implementation easier, I use scrollpane with disabling scroll bar at this stage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the point of this? If you try to resize the scrollpane to be the size of the text area then there is no need for the scrollpane.

Don't try to manage the sizes. Don't try to use the setPreferredSize() method.

Instead you can define the number of lines you want to display in the text area without scrolling by using the `setRows(...)` method of the `JTextArea`.

This will allow the text area to determine its preferred size based on the rows and Font of the text area. The scrollpane will automatically be sized to the preferred size of the text area.

If more lines of data are added, then scrollbars will appear.

Comment: I've solved it thanks to your advice. However, I used textArea.setRows(textArea.getLineCount()); then I got rows from textArea.getRows(); then I set the height of the textArea by textArea.setAlignmentX(rows); .. I removed setPreferredSize from scrollpane and as you said, scroll pane will be adjusted to the height of the textArea. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The way you are doing it, you are setting the height value as if the height of each line will be 1 pixel.

Multiply your line numbers by `Graphics.getFontMetrics().getHeight()`, where You have the font set on your Graphics. It should solve your problem

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Font class doesn't have getHeight function. Did you mean getSize..?  or you mean text in JTextArea!

Comment: @In-youngChoung No, not getSize. I have corrected my answer

Comment: @In-youngChoung again, sorry. Fixed again. I think it's right now

Comment: textArea.getHeight() returns zero (0).

Comment: I didn't see your replies lol I am seeing your new answer. I will try it.

Comment: I tried this way..
Graphics g = textArea.getGraphics();
  int test = g.getFontMetrics().getHeight();
test throws NullPointerException.

Comment: Calculating the font height is much more complicated then simply calling `getHeight`, you need to take into account the line spacing as well, ascent and descent.  The real question is why is the OP trying to resize the `JScrollPane` anyway, what's the point?

Comment: I answered the same question to @camickr above.
Thank you for your input.